# Initialize parent class array member in child class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is it possible in C# to write something like this that actually works (this compiles and runs, but doesn't work properly)?

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public int[] a;
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public int[] a = new int[123];
}
```

Or do I have to use this (works fine, but doesn't seem as nice as the above code)?

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public int[] a;

    public void Init(int size)
    {
        a = new int[size];
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar()
    {
        Init(123);
    }
}
```

Comment: define "work properly": what do you want to achieve? the first is shadowing `a` in the base class, which can get quite confusing. using the constructor is usually preferable over a redeclaration, but as said, depends on the intention.

Comment: You should do this public int[] a = new int[123]; either in the base abstract class or if you expect the child class to implement it you should mark it as abastract as well public abstract int[] a;

Comment: In Bar just write _a = new int[123];_ without redeclaring a inherited by the abstract class

Comment: @Isma I think protected would be better here.

Comment: What specifically do you want to accomplish here?  "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything when we don't know what you *expect* it to do.  It *looks like* you're just asking how to use a constructor.

Comment: The intention is to have the child class set the array size. In the actual project, the base class is a pseudo random number generator base class (with seeder method, etc), while the child classes each contain a PRNG, where the state size of each PRNG can be different.

Comment: @jumper0x08 sure, my bad: protected abstract int[] a; it is

Comment: @Steve How is this possible without declaring a method or constructor in `Bar`?

Comment: Why was my question down voted?

Answer (score 2):

The `Bar.a` hides inherited base member (`Foo.a`). To make this works properly, *firstly*, you need to change your base member from field to property and *secondly* declare it as `abstract` and then [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties) it in your derived class. Something like this:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract int[] a { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override int[] a { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you only want to *have the child class set the array size* use [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) in your derived class like this:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public int[] a;
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar()
    {
        a = new int[123];
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment above:

> The intention is to have the child class set the array size.

It sounds like what you're looking for is called a **constructor**.  You would use it to define the required values for creating an instance of an object, and use those values to build the object.

Your base class would require the value, something like this:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public int[] a;

    public Foo(int size)
    {
        a = new int[size];
    }
}
```

So now one *needs* to supply the value for the constructor.  The child class can supply the value from its own constructor easily using constructor chaining:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar(int size) : base(size) { }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about constructor chaining, seems like a good solution.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen - In the actual project it can't, because it has to be alterable. The field holds a PRNG state, and it has to be possible to re-seed as necessary, and it also has to be possible to save and restore states of PRNGs.

Comment: @Thorham So do you actually write a new array instance to `a` (in which case it cannot be `readonly`), possibly with another `Length`? Or do you simply change the entries of `a`, i.e. mutate the existing array instance (in which case `readonly` ensures you do not accidentally substitute the array instance with another array instance)?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen - I mutate the existing array with Buffer.BlockCopy(). There's no reason to ever create a new instance.